# Why QFile("./test") work though [Class QFile] has no QFile(char* s) constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I check the *QT-Help*, I found that class `QFile` has the following constructors:

```
QFile()
QFile(const QString &name)
QFile(QObject *parent)
QFile(const QString &name, QObject *parent)
```

There is no `QFile(char *)` for class `QFile`
But `QFile("/home/mythicsr/test");` is ok, why?

Comment: QString supports initialization using char*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the statement:

```
QFile("/home/mythicsr/test");
```

It leads to the creation of a temporary object of type `QString` under the hood and thus the constructor `QFile(const QString &name)` is invoked.
As mentioned by @meetaig in the comments it's possible because:

> QString supports initialization using char*

Or better, as noted in the comments by @Slava - *`const char *` in this case*.

That's all.

Comment: `const char *` in this case